# Header Z-Index Renders Links Unclickable

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, z-index

The Z-Index of my fixed header is set at 1 and none of the other links on the page are clickable... When I tried switching the position to relative but left the Z-Index the links could be clicked. Is there any obvious solution I'm missing?

The URL to my blog is: www.simpleandspice.blogspot.com

Comment: You should include the relevant code in your question (ideally by making a minimal example), otherwise this question is not useful if the code on your site changes or if your site goes 404.

Comment: There are unclosed elements in your code, clean up your html and see if that doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Give **position:fixed**,instead of absolute position and Z index